# Crud Service RXJS Angular 9 Command Query Pattern

Tags: angular, rxjs, crud, cqrs

I am trying to build crud service in angular using rxjs.
I have product-service to communicate with backend with getall,getbyid,post,pust,delete methods
and top of that

product-facade-service which act as a store/service and exposes public api for component which is as follows :

```
import { CrudAction, CrudOperation } from 'src/app/shared/facade-base';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductFacadeService {

  constructor(private productService: ProductClient) { }

  // All products
  getProducts$ = this.productService.get()
    .pipe(
      tap(data => console.log('Products', JSON.stringify(data))),
      //shareReplay({bufferSize:1, refCount:1,}),
      //shareReplay(1),
    );

   private productCrudActionSubject = new Subject<CrudAction<ProductResource>>();

    productsWithUpdates$ = merge(
      this.getProducts$,
      this.productCrudActionSubject.asObservable(),
    )
      .pipe(
        scan((acc: ProductResource[], action: CrudAction<ProductResource>) => {

          if(action.operation === CrudOperation.Add){
            return [...acc,action.entity];
          }

          else if(action.operation === CrudOperation.Update){
            let updatedentity = acc.find(p => p['id'] == action.entity['id']);
            updatedentity = action.entity;
            return [...acc];
          }

        else if(action.operation === CrudOperation.Delete){
          let deletedEntity = acc.find(p => p['id'] == action.entity['id']);
          const index = acc.indexOf(deletedEntity);
          if(index > - 1){
            acc.splice(index,1)
          }
        }
        return [...acc];
        }),
        catchError(err => {
          console.error(err);
          return throwError(err);
        })
      );




  private addProductSubject = new Subject<ProductResource>();
  addProductAction$ = this.addProductSubject.pipe(
    mergeMap(productToBeAdded =>this.productService.post(productToBeAdded)),
    tap(newProduct => this.productCrudActionSubject.next({operation :CrudOperation.Add,entity:newProduct}))
  );

  private updateProductSubject = new Subject<ProductResource>();
  updateProductAction$ = this.updateProductSubject.pipe(
    mergeMap(productTobeUpdated =>this.productService.put(productTobeUpdated.id,productTobeUpdated)),
    tap(updatedProduct => this.productCrudActionSubject.next({operation :CrudOperation.Update,entity:updatedProduct}))
  );

  private deleteProductSubject = new Subject<ProductResource>();
  deleteProductAction$ = this.deleteProductSubject.pipe(
    mergeMap(productToBeDeleted => this.productService.delete(productToBeDeleted.id)),
    tap(deletedProduct => this.productCrudActionSubject.next({operation :CrudOperation.Delete,entity:deletedProduct}))
    );


private productSelectedSubject = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
selectedProduct$ = combineLatest([
  this.productsWithUpdates$,
  this.productSelectedSubject.asObservable()
]).pipe(
  concatMap(([products, selectedProductId]) => {
    if(selectedProductId === 0){
      return of(this.intialize())
    }
    var found = products ? products.find(product => product.id == selectedProductId) : null;
    if(found){
      return of(found);
    }
    else
      return this.productService.getById(selectedProductId);
  }),
);

//Public api for component to invoke command....
save(product:ProductResource){
  product.id === 0 ?
  this.addProductSubject.next(product)
  : this.updateProductSubject.next(product);
}
deleteProduct(product:ProductResource): void {
  this.deleteProductSubject.next(product);
}
selectProduct(selectedProductId: number): void {
  this.productSelectedSubject.next(+selectedProductId);
}

  private intialize(): ProductResource {
    return {
      id: 0,
      name: 'New',
      unit : 'New',
      pricePerUnitTaxInclusive :0,
    };
  }
}
```

Now I am tryin to build two components
product-list for showing products and user can delete if required and navigate user to add or edit product
product-form to create or edit new form and when created user to go back to product-list.

product-list.ts

```
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit{

  products$ = this.productService.productsWithUpdates$;


  constructor(
    private productService: ProductFacadeService,private toastr: ToastrService
    ) { }

    ngOnInit(){
//Code need improvement
      this.productService.deleteProductAction$.pipe(
        tap(deletedProduct=> this.toastr.success("Product Deleted :" + deletedProduct.name))
      ).subscribe();
    }


  onDelete(productToDelete){
    if (confirm(`Are you sure you want to delete Product : ${productToDelete.name}`)) {
      this.productService.deleteProduct(productToDelete);
      }
    }
}
```

product-form.ts

```
export class ProductFormComponent implements OnInit,OnDestroy {
  form: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    name: ['', Validators.required],
    unit: ['', Validators.required],
    pricePerUnitTaxInclusive: [, Validators.required],
  });;

  product$= this.productClient.selectedProduct$.pipe(
    tap(res =>{
      this.form.patchValue({
        name: res.name,
        unit: res.unit,
        pricePerUnitTaxInclusive: res.pricePerUnitTaxInclusive,
      })
    })
  );

//Code need improvement
   onSave$ =  combineLatest([this.productClient.addProductAction$.pipe(tap(product => this.toastr.success("New Produt Added : " + product.name))),
                            this.productClient.updateProductAction$.pipe(tap(product => this.toastr.success("Product Updated : " + product.name)))]
                           )
                            .subscribe(() => this.onSaveComplete());

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(param => {
      this.productClient.selectProduct(param['id']);
    });
  }
  ngOnDestroy(){
    // this.onSave$.unsubscribe();
  }

  save(product:ProductResource): void {
    console.log("Save invoked")
    this.productClient.save(Object.assign({},product,this.form.value));
  }

  private onSaveComplete(): void {
    this.form.reset();
    this.router.navigate(['../'], { relativeTo: this.route });
  }
}
```

the codes behave differently as it issues more that one delete put or post command...dont know where i am making mistake.. as I am new to rxjs.
Also any suggestions welcome for how to avoid subscribing on ts.
I have marked them with comments (//Code needs improvement.)

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what's not working in your code? But if you need the component to know when the update or delete operations are complete, you may want to define a separate action stream (Subject) that emits on complete. Also, in your delete code, instead of a find you could use a filter to filter out the one that was deleted. Something like: `return heroes.filter(h => h.id !== heroAction.hero.id);`

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-trfftx?file=src/app/product-facade.service.ts
I have created a sample and mimic product client.

the problem is http method are invoked more than once...it is behaving indifferently....

Comment: I have update posts module in it... it talks with json place holder.com...
It issues multiple delete method... try creating new post edit and delete.... alert box pops up more than once for delete ,add or update....because it issues multiple http request.... @DeborahK

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hpheae?file=src/app/post-form/post-form.component.html


Please use this link... as the above link is not working

Comment: To fix your immediately issue, you need a shareReplay(1) in the .pipe after the scan. Otherwise the array managed by the scan is not being reused appropriately across operations. That should resolve it for you.

Comment: i don't have much time to investigate but mergeMap can lead to multiple call sometime, have to tried to replace mergeMap by switchMap ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is the updated code with the `shareReplay(1)` in place. As I mentioned above, it's needed after the `scan`. Otherwise, the array managed by the `scan` is not reused appropriately across operations.

```
productsWithUpdates$ = merge(
  this.getProducts$,
  this.productCrudActionSubject.asObservable(),
)
  .pipe(
    scan((acc: PostResource[], action: CrudAction<PostResource>) => {

      if(action.operation === CrudOperation.Add){
        return [...acc,action.entity];
      }

      else if(action.operation === CrudOperation.Update){
        let updatedentity = acc.find(p => p['id'] == action.entity['id']);
        updatedentity = action.entity;
        return [...acc];
      }

    else if(action.operation === CrudOperation.Delete){
      let deletedEntity = acc.find(p => p['id'] == action.entity['id']);
      const index = acc.indexOf(deletedEntity);
      if(index > - 1){
        acc.splice(index,1)
      }
    }
    return [...acc];
    }),
    shareReplay(1),           // <----------- HERE
    catchError(err => {
      console.error(err);
      return throwError(err);
    })
  );
```

I also did an update to the Stackblitz that you can find here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-crud-deborahk

Though I made significant changes from your original in this stackblitz, including changing the update to a one line `map` and the delete to a one line `filter`.